# PostAsync with two strings using HttpClient and HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, parameters, http-post, httpclient, httpresponse

I'm trying to perform an Http POST call with two strings using HttpClient and HttpResponseMessage.

Here's my code that calls the post:

```
public async Task Convert()
{
    string url = "http://localhost:5000/convert/files";
    string stringValue1 = "test1";
    string stringValue2 = "test2";

    var x = await ConvertFiles(stringValue1, stringValue2, url);
}

public async static Task<string> ConvertFiles(string s1, string s2, string webAddress)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    StringContent sc = new StringContent("");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(webAddress, sc);
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + content);
    return content;
}
```

I believe I have to use StringContent, but I'm not sure how (which is why it is empty).

Here's my HttpPost call:

```
[HttpPost("/mshdf/import")]
public string ConvertFiles([FromBody]string s1, [FromBody]string s2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string1: " + s1);
    Console.WriteLine("string2: " + s2);
    return "woo";
}
```

I've just started using HttpClient and HttpResponseMessage. Right now, the call doesn't occur - I'm guessing this is due to the fact that I'm not sending both strings s1 and s2 properly.

Comment: only one `[FromBody]` parameter is allowed (there's only one body after all). You can make a class with two string properties and send that, or send FormUrlEncoded content instead of StringContent.

Comment: Thanks! I'll write a formal answer and credit you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Thanks to CrowCoder for his post.

I ended up making a Dictionary which contained my values.

```
public async static Task<string> ConvertFiles(string s1, string s2, string webAddress)
{
    Dictionary<string, string> jsonValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    jsonValues.Add("string1", "anyStringValue1");
    jsonValues.Add("string2", "anyStringValue2");

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    StringContent sc = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonValues), UnicodeEncoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(webAddress, sc);
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + content);
    return content;
}
```

Now you just need to use a dynamic type to access string1 and string2 like this:

```
[HttpPost("/mshdf/import")]
public string ConvertFiles([FromBody]dynamic jsonObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine("string1: " + jsonObject.string1);
    Console.WriteLine("string2: " + jsonObject.string2);
    return "woo";
}
```

Comment: You should dispose the HttpClient at least.

Comment: No, you shouldn't dispose the HttpClient: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/antipatterns/improper-instantiation/

Answer (score 2):

This is not the only way but should work. It assumes the Nuget package System.Net.Http v4.1.0 is used, not the assembly you can add from References.

```
public async static Task<string> ConvertFiles(string s1, string s2, string webAddress)
{
    using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Cleare();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

        List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> formFields = new List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>();
        formFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("s1", s1));
        formFields.Add(new KeyValuePair<string,string>("s2", s2));
        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formFields);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(webAddress, formContent);
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + content);
        return content;
    }
}

[HttpPost("/mshdf/import")]
public string ConvertFiles(FormDataCollection data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.Get("s1"));
    Console.WriteLine(data.Get("s2"));
    return "woo";
}
```